# Django error when installing Graphite - settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I am trying to install GRAPHITE on ubuntu. I follow the  instructions in the blog.

```
http://geek.michaelgrace.org/2011/09/how-to-install-graphite-on-ubuntu/
```

When I get to the part where I run the command..I get the below error.  I have zero clue on how to resolve.  I am using the lastest version of Django 1.4.

```
cd /opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/
sudo python manage.py syncdb


sudo python manage.py syncdb
/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/thirdparty/pytz/__init__.py:32: UserWarning: Module pytz was already imported from /opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/thirdparty/pytz/__init__.pyc, but /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytz-2012b-py2.7.egg is being added to sys.path
  from pkg_resources import resource_stream
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 459, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 57, in handle_noargs
    cursor = connection.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py", line 15, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

In the /opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/settings.py file, this is the contents.

```
#Database settings, sqlite is intended for single-server setups
DATABASE_ENGINE = 'sqlite3'                     # 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'ado_mssql'.
DATABASE_NAME = STORAGE_DIR + 'graphite.db'     # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
DATABASE_USER = ''                              # Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_PASSWORD = ''                          # Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_HOST = ''                              # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_PORT = ''                              # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.

DASHBOARD_CONF = join(CONF_DIR, 'dashboard.conf')
GRAPHTEMPLATES_CONF = join(CONF_DIR, 'graphTemplates.conf')
```

Answer (score 14):

[graphite version 0.9.10 supports Django 1.4](https://bugs.launchpad.net/graphite/+bug/963684)... however they put the sqlite settings in django's `local_settings.py`

```
[mpenning@tsunami graphite]$ cat local_settings.py|grep -v \#
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': '/opt/graphite/storage/graphite.db',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': ''
    }
}
[mpenning@tsunami graphite]$
[mpenning@tsunami graphite]$ pwd
/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite
[mpenning@tsunami graphite]$
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to edit `settings.py` and set the contents of the `DATABASES` variable to something other than empty strings. There are comments next to it that tell you which database engines are supported:

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

If you have nothing else installed, you could append `sqlite3` to the `ENGINE` string which is easy for development on your local machine.

Comment: What version of Django are you using? Your settings file has multiple `DATABASE_` variables in it (which is the old way of doing it) while your Django seems to be looking for the `DATABASES` variable (which is the new way to configure database settings).

Comment: Solved...I removed django 1.4 and installed using sudo apt-get install python-django.  I guess graphite does not like 1.4

Answer (score 9):

For users landing here with the error message "The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty", make sure to set the secret key in /opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/app_settings.py as well as in your django config.

Answer (score 1):

I just add the DATABASES dictionary to the end of the file, it works.I hope the the graphite can run based on the Django 1.4.1